# LocalDateTime misformated with @Query, the seconds are removed

Tags: spring-data-elasticsearch

I have a mapping similar to this one :

```
        @Field(type = FieldType.Date, format = DateFormat.custom, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
        private LocalDateTime startTime;

        @Field(type = FieldType.Date, format = DateFormat.custom, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
        private LocalDateTime endTime;
```

And a request in a repository like this :

```
    @Query("{" +
            "    \"nested\": {" +
            "      \"path\" : \"panel.channels\"," +
            "      \"query\" : {" +
            "        \"bool\" : {" +
            "          \"must\" : [" +
            "              { \"range\" : { \"panel.channels.startTime\" : { \"lte\": \"?1\" } } }," +
            "              { \"range\" : { \"panel.channels.endTime\" :   { \"gte\": \"?0\"  } } } " +
            "          ]" +
            "        }" +
            "      }" +
            "    }" +
            "}")
    Flux<Document> search(LocalDateTime from, LocalDateTime to);
```

If I provide date times with the seconds at zero, at start of day for instance, like 2021-03-15T00:00:00, the date is not well formatted and the requests returns no result, with this error in the logs (in the ES response) :

```
"caused_by":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"failed to parse date field [2021-03-15T00:00] with format [yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss]"
```

When I check the requests is really wrong :

```
{
  "nested": {
    "path": "panel.channels",
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "must": [
          {
            "range": {
              "panel.channels.startTime": {
                "lte": "2021-03-15T00:00"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "range": {
              "panel.channels.endTime": {
                "gte": "2020-01-01T00:00"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But if there's seconds in the LocalDateTime, like `2021-03-15T00:00:01`, is works !

Comment: Which version of Spring Data Elasticsearch are you using?

Comment: I could reproduce that, will investigate further.

Answer (score 0):

I did some debugging and testing; so what is happening here?

You have defined a custom date format with the `@Field` annotation on your properties. By this, internally for each
of these properties a custom converter is created that can convert from a `LocalDateTime` to a `String` in the
desired format and back. **Important:** This converter is attached to the property of the entity and not a generally available converter for
`LocalDateTime` (you might have different formats for different properties). This converter is then used when Spring
Data Elasticsearch stores or retrieves an entity.

Things get more complicated when doing a query. When you create for example a `CriteriaQuery` Spring Data Elasticsearch
knows
which properties are used in the query and can use the corresponding converter to correctly convert the property
values to query parameters. This is not possible with a query that is defined by the `@Query` annotation on a
repository method. These queries are just used as strings and the paramater parts (`?0`, `?1`) are replaced by the
converted parameter values of the method. *converted* here means converted by the default conversions that are
available, not the ones attached to the property, because we don't know to which property of an entity a parameter
might relate. We would need to implement a query parser that finds the corresponding property - in your case
`panel.channels.startTime` - to get the converter and I don't think that we will implement such a parser.

So in your case the default conversion service is searched for a converter for a `LocalDateTime` instance, and there
is no one registered. Then a fallback is used whcih calls `toString()` on the object to be converted and this in case
of zero seconds returns the strings that you see - just containing the hours and minutes, that's the implementation
of `LocalDateTime.toString()` that returns this.

The first workaround that came to my mind is to define a converter for `LocalDateTime` -> `String` and register that
in Spring Data Elasticsearch, but I found that this is not used by the `@Query` parameter resolution - which
definitely is a bug - that I will fix tomorrow. The next round of maintenance releases for Spring Data Elasticsearch
4.1, 4.2 and the current main branch is next friday, so you could get that change pretty fast. I tried that already
locally and the produced query is built correctly.

Another possible solution might be to introduce additional property hint annotations on the method parameters, that
would be something like

```java
Flux<Document> search(
    @Property("panel.channels.endTime") LocalDateTime from, 
    @Property("panel.channels.startTime") LocalDateTime to);
```

but to be honest, I don't like this.

When I have the fix implemented and the fixed versions are released, I would edit this answer with the additional
information about how to add the converter to your setup and get this running.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I ended up formating the date to string before calling the method.